Unity AAB exceeds 200 MB compressed size limit despite enabling 'Split Application Binary
I am trying to upload my Unity game to Google Play Console, but I am encountering the following error:
"Some feature modules in the application package exceed the maximum compressed download size of 200 MB. Reduce the size of these modules: base."
Usually, enabling the 'Split Application Binary' option in Unity resolves this issue. However, I have already enabled this option, and I am still facing the error. My AAB file size is 308 MB.
Here is what I've tried so far:

Ensured 'Split Application Binary' is enabled.
Reduced the size of assets and resources in the project.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. What steps can I take to resolve this issue? Are there any additional settings or configurations I should consider in Unity or the Google Play Console?
Thank you for your help!
Here is what I've tried so far:

Ensured 'Split Application Binary' is enabled.
Reduced the size of assets and resources in the project.


have you looked at the logs to determine the sizes of things in the build file?

I had the same problem. I don't know which of the thousand things I did worked, but in my last try, I deleted all the .meta files with a Python script.

I had same problem, Not found any other answers and just optimized till 200mb and uploaded successfully
